# Terraform: Map Set of Complex Objects to List of a specific property

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I'm having a complex set of complex objects, e.g. DynamoDB tables received via data

```
data "aws_dynamodb_table" "table" {
  for_each = toset([
    "table-1",
    "table-2",
    "table-3",
  ])
  name     = each.value
}
```

I want to use some of the table properties in different places, e.g. creating event source mappings to lambda functions, which is quite easy:

```
resource "aws_lambda_event_source_mapping" "mapping" {
  for_each          = data.aws_dynamodb_table.table
  batch_size        = 100
  event_source_arn  = each.value.stream_arn
  function_name     = // some function ARN
  starting_position = "LATEST"
}
```

**Now where I'm stuck**: how do it just get a list of some specific field like the table ARN, so that I can use that directly in a IAM policy for the resources?

```
statement {
  actions = [
    "dynamodb:PutItem",
    "dynamodb:UpdateItem",
    "dynamodb:Query",
    "dynamodb:Scan"
  ]
  # that's not how it works
  resources = tolist(data.aws_dynamodb_table.table.*.arn)
  effect = "Allow"
}
```

I'm sure the terraform documentation gives me an answer on that, but I'm not able to find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your `data.aws_dynamodb_table.table` is a **map** due to the use of `for_each`, you have to use `values` to get all the values for the arn:

```
 resources = values(data.aws_dynamodb_table.table)[*].arn
```

Comment: Thank you very much :) that did the trick

Comment: @tpschmidt No problem. Glad it worked out:-)